# How to expand all rows to be followed by a new blank row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

The straightforward technique is

1. highlight all but top row.
2. cut
3. paste to next row.

However that requires to repeat steps 1-3 for N rows.

Is there a fast way to add a blank row to follow each existing row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating a macro

```
Sub AddBlankRows()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection
    Set CurrentSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    firstSelRow = rng.Rows(1).Row
    totalSelRows = rng.Rows.Count

    For idx = 1 To totalSelRows Step 1
        curRow = (idx - 1) * 2 + firstSelRow
        Cells(curRow, 1).EntireRow.Insert
    Next idx
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on number of rows you have, here is a more advanced process:

1. select 2nd row
2. press and hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>
3. Select next row (by clicking on its number in the left)
4. repeat step 3 as necessary
5. release <kbd>CTRL</kbd>
6. right click on left "header"(where you see row numbers) and select insert.